# Is it possible to get text-to-speech of Bengali language in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, text-to-speech, swift4

Is it possible to use text-to-speech of Bengali language in Swift 4? If you know, please explain how to do it.

Comment: Google Cloud Speech does support Bengali. But I have no idea how good it is: https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/languages

Answer (score 1):

No,Only Hindi Language is supportedin AVSpeechSynthesizer. You can find the list here.

```
Arabic (Saudi Arabia) - ar-SA
Chinese (China) - zh-CN
Chinese (Hong Kong SAR China) - zh-HK
Chinese (Taiwan) - zh-TW
Czech (Czech Republic) - cs-CZ
Danish (Denmark) - da-DK
Dutch (Belgium) - nl-BE
Dutch (Netherlands) - nl-NL
English (Australia) - en-AU
English (Ireland) - en-IE
English (South Africa) - en-ZA
English (United Kingdom) - en-GB
English (United States) - en-US
Finnish (Finland) - fi-FI
French (Canada) - fr-CA
French (France) - fr-FR
German (Germany) - de-DE
Greek (Greece) - el-GR
Hebrew (Israel) - he-IL
Hindi (India) - hi-IN
Hungarian (Hungary) - hu-HU
Indonesian (Indonesia) - id-ID
Italian (Italy) - it-IT
Japanese (Japan) - ja-JP
Korean (South Korea) - ko-KR
Norwegian (Norway) - no-NO
Polish (Poland) - pl-PL
Portuguese (Brazil) - pt-BR
Portuguese (Portugal) - pt-PT
Romanian (Romania) - ro-RO
Russian (Russia) - ru-RU
Slovak (Slovakia) - sk-SK
Spanish (Mexico) - es-MX
Spanish (Spain) - es-ES
Swedish (Sweden) - sv-SE
Thai (Thailand) - th-TH
Turkish (Turkey) - tr-TR
```

Comment: that is not matter for me. my question is. how can do text-to-speach in bengli

Comment: I dont think so, iOS supports this. I had used few third party api's for tts but they doesn't used to support indian regional languages.